# App closes with "application has stopped unexpectedly" when getting user's current location

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am using this code to find current location.

My overlay is working properly but I can't get current longitude and latitude.  The app closes with the message "application has stopped unexpectedly" when getting user's current location.

I have studied some tutorial about finding location but I can't solve it.

```
package google.com;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import java.util.*;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import android.location.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class nandyog extends MapActivity implements LocationListener{

      LocationManager locManager;   
      Location location;
      double lat;
      double lng;

     Boolean network_enabled;
     Boolean gps_enabled;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconr);
        HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(locManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        lat = loc.getLatitude();
        lng = loc.getLongitude();
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Current Location","LAL-DARWAJA");

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }






    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();


    }






    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }






    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }
}
/*
final class GPoint extends GeoPoint {
    public GPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
        super((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
    }
}
*/
```

My manifest file is below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="google.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>




    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
      >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".nandyog"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"  
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat errors are...

08-31 18:55:49.226: D/dalvikvm(368): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1164K, 54% free 3148K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 6ms+5ms
08-31 18:55:49.536: D/dalvikvm(368): GC_CONCURRENT freed 529K, 51% free 3307K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 6ms+6ms
08-31 18:55:50.065: D/AndroidRuntime(368): Shutting down VM
08-31 18:55:50.076: W/dalvikvm(368): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{google.com/google.com.nandyog}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at google.com.nandyog.onCreate(nandyog.java:46)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-31 18:55:50.105: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  ... 11 more
08-31 18:55:50.365: D/dalvikvm(368): GC_CONCURRENT freed 838K, 54% free 3119K/6727K, external 1986K/2137K, paused 4ms+32ms
08-31 18:56:09.355: I/Process(368): Sending signal. PID: 368 SIG: 9

Comment: You should take a look at the logcat. you're probably getting an exception there. Follow the linenumber and check what's wrong. If you can't figure it out, post the log here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to get boolean from this:

```
network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

and you should access `NETWORK_PROVIDER` in static way like this

```
Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

not

```
Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(locManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: I Should access NETWORK_PROVIDER in static way but it is not work properly and give same error